The local machine does not support running projects complied for the ARM64 architecture

I'm facing this issue while trying to finish build. I have all the necessary packages .
I'm searching all the possible reasons and solutions for this. I'm trying to fix this error for the past 1 week and I'm back to square one!!!
I want to choose Release: ARM64:Device option
But unfortunately I'm not able to get Device option For ARM64

Im not sure here a i dont write for vr and dont recognise the d3d build type. But if i select windows and arm64 i get remote options

Thank you for your suggestion. I will check this and give my update

Here you can't directly run this project. To build and deploy your application to HoloLens 2, the best practice is to select ‘Build and Run on’ as ‘Local Machine’ and choose ‘Build’ instead of ‘Build And Run’ to generate the Visual Studio project first. With Visual Studio, you can then deploy your application to HoloLens 2 via a wireless network or a USB cable. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2.

Thank you for your suggestion. I will check this and give my update
